# MySQL - GET name of parent LEFT JOIN on PARENTID

Tags: mysql

I have a single table of organizations and users on multiple levels.
They are connected with `parentId` and `MEMBERID`. (lover level parenId is memberid of parent)

```
    -------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------
    MEMBERID     LEVEL          NAME         MEMBERKIND       EMAIL          parentId
    -------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------*/*------------
    EMD123F |     2        |   OrgName1   |     Org      |              |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    DHAD781 |     3        |   UserName1  |    Person    | john@doe.com |  EMD123F 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    7AJIZU7 |     3        |   UserName2  |    Person    | doe@john.com |  EMD123F 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    DME123F |     2        |   OrgName2   |     Org      |              |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TT5451AL|     3        |   UserName3  |    Person    | din@don.com  |  DME123F 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    RRMI7481|     2        |   OrgName3   |     Org      |              |  rootID 
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    PPUNSAD9|     2        |   OrgName4   |     Org      |              |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    GJASDNZB|     3        |   UserName4  |    Person    | bon@ton.com  |  PPUNSAD9
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    KJNSCZM7|     2        |   OrgName5   |     Org      |              |  rootID
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1UZGOPAS|     3        |   UserName5  |    Person    |  kon@kon.com |  KJNSCZM7
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I need to write a SELECT which get:
1. name, email of all Persons
2. organization name of all  Persons

Result should looks like:

```
--------------------------------------------
UserName2 |   doe@john.com   |   OrgName1  |  
--------------------------------------------
```

Query I tryed

```
SELECT  c.EMAIL, c.NAME, c.PARENTID                      
            FROM users AS c
            LEFT JOIN users as ce on c.PARENTID = ce.MEMBERID           
            WHERE `MEMBERKIND`= "Person"
            GROUP BY c.EMAIL, c.LOGIN, c.PARENTID;
```

how ever I get error: Column 'MEMBERKIND' in where clause is ambiguous 
I 'm not even sure if I am doing it right so any advise is helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT u1.Name, u1.Email, u2.Name
FROM users u1
JOIN users u2 ON(u2.MEMBERID = u1.parentId)
WHERE u1.MEMBERKIND='Person'
```

Comment: Cool it works, i will mark this answer as correct as soon as I will be able